# Multiple Exposes on Nested Array Object with Class Transformer

Tags: node.js, typescript, class-transformer

I'm working with class transformers and I've been running into issues transforming a nested array. The example in question:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "data": {
        "books": [
          {
            "name": "book1",
            "type": "hardcover"
          },
          {
            "name": "book2",
            "type": "hardcover"
          }
        ]
      }
    }  
  ]
}
```

I would like to transform the values inside books by existence:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "book1": true,
      "book2": true
    }  
  ]
}
```

I've tried this as my entity:

```
export class Product {
  @Expose({ name: 'data' })
  @Transform(({value}) => value.books.filter((book) => book.name == 'book1').length > 0)
  book1: boolean;

  @Expose({ name: 'data' })
  @Transform(({value}) => value.books.filter((book) => book.name == 'book2').length > 0)
  book2: boolean;
}

export class Products {
  @Type(() => Product)
  @Expose({ name: 'products' })
  products: Array<Product>;

  constructor(partial: Partial<Products>) {
    plainToClassFromExist(this, partial);
  }
}
```

However, only 1 is transformed because the expose is on 'data'. Am I taking the right approach with this library, would really appreciate some insight on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue that was reported on https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/1503

As a workaround, you can use the `obj` in `@Transform`

```
export class Product {
  @Expose()
  @Transform(({obj}) => obj.data.books.filter((book) => book.name == 'book1').length > 0)
  book1: boolean;

  @Expose()
  @Transform(({obj}) => obj.data.books.filter((book) => book.name == 'book2').length > 0)
  book2: boolean;
}
```